# Most optimized query to render a grid of items that have 1:n relationships, is using group_concat?

Tags: php, mysql, json, relationship, group-concat

It seems to me that using `GROUP_CONCAT()` performs best when querying data to render a list view, that would require several separate queries, when not using `GROUP_CONCAT()` (with big tables). Is this true in any case?

And are there any other downsides, besides having `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` to be large enough?

It is quite easy to use as well when you let MySQL do the dirty work; this generates valid json (generated sql):

```
<<<SQL
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[{', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        '"id":"', table.id, 
        '"' "," '"filename":"', REPLACE('"', '\"', table.filenamehash), 
        '"' "," '"originalname":"', REPLACE('"', '\"', table.originalname), 
        '"'
      ) SEPARATOR '},{'
    ), 
    '}]'
  ) AS file_data
SQL;
```

Comment: If any of the values contain quotes or backslash, they won't be escaped properly.

Comment: That is a major downside. I'd sacrifice some performance to overcome this. I have added REPLACE functions to overcome this problem, I think this should suffice ?